# Angular, move home npm package

Tags: angular, npm-package

Our app is using a deprecated angular npm library.
I would like to move "home" some components to our local app from the external library.
When I look in the external npm library I just see files like componentname.component.d.ts and a bunch of map files (there are for example no html files).

Is it possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Did you check the if there is a github repo behind the package ?